# Number Slider for exposed filter using Drupal 6

Tags: 6, views

I need to expose the number fields in views with the **range slider**, for example : **Min- 421 and Max 780**.

[image]

I found this [slider Field](https://drupal.org/project/sliderfield) module, but it support only for Drupal 7. **any idea for Drupal 6 ?**

I don't want to use **Better Exposed Filter** module, because the plugins mentioned in the documentation are not there and hard to configure the options. Looking for any other alternate way.

Answer (score 0):

[Better Exposed Filters](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) has that functionality built in

> ...
>
> **What else can I do with BEF?**
>
> - Use the jQuery Slider widget for greater-than, less-than or in-between types of filters

I've never used it for D6 but the project page doesn't mention the slider being missing from that version or anything so it should be there.

Comment: jQuery Slider widget - I can't find the widget

Comment: I searched the widget with google, but I can not find the widget, do you know the jQuery Slider widget project page

Comment: It's part of [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), so it's already included with core

Comment: I tried that, but it is very hard to do that, still not able to setup properly.

Comment: If the module doesn't work as advertised you might want to report it as a bug

Comment: I'm looking for any other simpler way to achieve this, since this module is hard to configure.